# how to add resize photos to my site ? , how to ftp photos to server

Tags: php, upload, photo, resize

I have the necessity to upload some photos to my server (giving users the capability to), but before doing it, I need the user to be able to resize the photo, like they do in picasa when the pic is to big, or online in this sites, [reducePhoto.com](http://www.reducephoto.com/) or [shrinkPictures.com](http://www.shrinkpictures.com/)

that is task one... now for the second task,  need to add some ftp functionality, so the user can upload the photos to the server(like filezilla style, but with some web site front page that the user just select what to upload, and clicks "upload")

- hopefully using PHP

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a php expert, but it looks like there are image functions available. See the php api:

http://vn2.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

and notably, the imagecopyresized function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

As for uploading files via a website form..there are tons of exmamples of this online. You should try google first.

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php